# Selecting child of closest parent jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, parent, closest

I have the following card header in my view:

```
<div class="card-header">
    <div class="media">
        <div class="media-body media-middle">
            <h4 class="card-title">{{ category.name }}</h4>
            <p class="card-subtitle">{{ category.description }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="media-right media-middle">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addForumPostModal" class="btn btn-white btn-sm add-post-button"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I am trying to get the category name when I click on the add-post-button

I tried the following jquery but it just printed undefined:

```
$('.add-post-button').on('click', function (){
    console.log($(this).closest('media').children('card-title').html())
});
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use `.find()` instead of `.children()` - the latter only looks at immediate children, not grandchildren, etc., whereas `.find()` looks for descendants at any level.

Also, to select by class you need a `'.'` before the class name, so `'.media'` and `'.card-title'` rather than `'media'` and `'card-title'`.

```js
$('.add-post-button').on('click', function (){
    console.log($(this).closest('.media').find('.card-title').html())
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="card-header">
    <div class="media">
        <div class="media-body media-middle">
            <h4 class="card-title">{{ category.name }}</h4>
            <p class="card-subtitle">{{ category.description }}</p>
        </div>
        <div class="media-right media-middle">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#addForumPostModal" class="btn btn-white btn-sm add-post-button"><i class="material-icons">add</i></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ... and probably mention that `.text` is better than `.html`!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir - Well, probably. We don't know exactly what the OP wants to do with the value.

Comment: I'm reading the value "x", setting the value of a hidden input to "x" in my form so it posts it to my api on submit :)

Comment: Then yes, I'd use `.text()` rather than `.html()`.

Comment: I had it set closest and find at one point but I was missing the '.' in front of my classes! Thanks!